# Producer-Consumer in C++ - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, producer-consumer

To expand from the changes supplied by the answer of my previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104988/producer-consumer-in-c):

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// global variables
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
std::vector<char> data;

int count = 0, buff_size = 0;

char random_char() {
    thread_local std::random_device seed;
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(seed());
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist('A', 'Z');

    return static_cast<char>(dist(generator));
}

/* Consumer

Prints out the contents of the shared buffer.

*/
void consume() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

    while (count == 0) {
        cv.wait(lck);
    }

    for (const auto& it : data) {
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
    }

    count--;
}

/* Producer

Randomly generates capital letters in the range of A to Z,
prints out those letters in lowercase, and then
inserts them into the shared buffer.

*/
void produce() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

    char c = random_char();
    std::cout << " " << static_cast<char>(tolower(c)) << std::endl;
    data.push_back(c);

    count++;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "The Producer-Consumer Problem (in C++11!)" << std::endl << "Enter the buffer size: ";
    std::cin >> buff_size;

    // keep the buffer in-range of the alphabet
    if (buff_size < 0) {
        buff_size = 0;
    }
    else if (buff_size > 26) {
        buff_size = 26;
    }

    std::thread production[26], processed[26];

    // initialize the arrays
    for (int order = 0; order < buff_size; order++) {
        production[order] = std::thread(produce);
        processed[order] = std::thread(consume);
    }

    // join the threads to the main threads
    for (int order = 0; order < buff_size; order++) {
        processed[order].join();
        production[order].join();
    }

    std::cout << "Succeeded with a shared buffer of " << data.size() << " letters!";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables in the best of cases are questionable, but in this case especially you have `buff_size` as a global variable. `buff_size` is only used in `main()` so should be a local variable there.

You can also take advantage of the fact that [`std::condition_variable::wait()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) has another overload that takes a predicate to replace:

```
while (count == 0) {
    cv.wait(lck);
}
```

with:

```
cv.wait(lck, []{ return count > 0; });
```

Although, did you really want every consumer to print out *every* letter every time? If `buff_size` were 10, you'd end up logging 55 letters. Was that intentional? If it wasn't, you could drop `count` entirely, switch `data` to be a `std::queue` and have your consumer be:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
cv.wait(lck, []{return !data.empty(); });
std::cout << data.front() << std::endl;
data.pop();
```

On the producer front, did you really mean `notify_one()` and not `notify_all()`? Let all the consumers fight for the lock!

Lastly, this:

```
if (buff_size < 0) {
    buff_size = 0;
}
else if (buff_size > 26) {
    buff_size = 26;
}
```

is a clamp. It might be worth writing something like:

```
template <typename T>
T clamp(T const& val, T const& lo, T const& hi)
{
    return std::min(std::max(val, lo), hi);
}

buff_size = clamp(buff_size, 0, 26);
```

Comment: Wouldn't their be some draw back to letting all of the consumers fight each other? What's the benefit of allowing it?

Comment: What about if I wanted the buffer to filled completely before the consumer begins working on it?

Comment: @T145 The drawback of all consumers fighting each other is possibility of Starvation. [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science) ]
This would occur if one consumer could not get its desired resource. 
Letting all consumers wait while buffer is not full is extremely inefficient, producer might be slow, certain consumers (in practice) might not even need whole produce.